# Animated gif image to individual tiff images capturing individual frames

Tags: image, image-processing

I have a small problem, I have a set of animated gif images. I want to pick individual gif image files, and create multiple tiff images capturing individual frames.

I am looking to do it in Python/Java.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily from the command-line using ImageMagick. It is available for free from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org). It has bindings for Perl, C/C++, Python and lots of others. It is ready installed in many Linux distros.

Your command looks like this:

```
convert -coalesce input.gif %02d.tif
```

which will produce TIFF format output files, numbered 01.tif, 02.tif etc. according to the frame number.

You can also extract an individual frame, say frame 7, like this:

```
convert -coalesce input.gif[7] my_favourite.tif
```

or a sequence of frames, say 3-7 like this:

```
convert -coalesce input.gif[3-7] frames%02d.tif
```

**Note** however, that when you extract individual frames, you may get artefacts depending on how well compressed your original GIF files are - since they sometimes only store DIFFERENCES between frames, so you may be best advised to extract all frames then discard any you don't want.